# Maximal function controlled by n th power of radial function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I struggled by a problem which is my homework this week.

Here is the statement of the problem：

> Assume $f\in L_{loc}^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Prove: If $f(x)=O(|x|^{-n})(|x|\to \infty)$, then $Mf(x)=O(|x|^{-n}\log|x|)(|x|\to \infty)$.

Here $Mf(x)$ is the maximal function i.e. $Mf(x)=\sup_{r>0}\frac{1}{|B(r,x)|}\int_{B(r,x)}|f(t)|\mathrm{d}t$

$f(x)=O(|x|^{-n})(|x|\to \infty)$ means $\left| \frac{f(x)}{|x|^{-n}}\right|\leq A$ for some $A>0$ held when $|x|$ large enough.

The main obstacle is I failed to get the form from directly using the inequality and intergal.Maybe I just lack some skills of intergal.

Any hints or references are highly welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $r$ large (depending on $x$) you have that $B(x,r)\subset B(0, Cr)\setminus B(0,cr)$. Integrate the function $g(y)=|y|^{-n}$ in $B(0,Cr)\setminus B(0,cr)$ using polar coordinates.

Comment: I'm too insistence for integral on the ball centred on x to overlook the annul, thanks.